# What is the purpose of synchronizing the traversal block if we are using Collections.synchrnizedList(Collection c)?

Tags: java, collections

What is the purpose of synchronizing the traversal block if we are using Collections.synchrnizedList(Collection c)?

I am using Collections.synchronizedList() method to get a synchronised version of arrayList,then why am I supposed to put the traversal of arraylist in a synchronised block?

So, I am going through a tutorial on how to make arraylist synchronous. I came across following line of code.

import java.util.*;

```
class GFG 
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 
        List<String> list = 
           Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>()); 

        list.add("practice"); 
        list.add("code"); 
        list.add("quiz"); 

        synchronized(list) 
        { 
            // must be in synchronized block 
            Iterator it = list.iterator(); 

            while (it.hasNext()) 
                System.out.println(it.next()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

My question is why are we synchronizing the traversal?
Even if there were to be two threads traversing simultaneously and if both try to structurally modify array simultaneously it should not be possible bcz if one thread is adding element won't it have lock over the synchronised arraylist?

Comment: Note that the `Collections.synchronizedXXX` methods simply _wrap_ the argument. So in your case you get a syncrhonized `List` but it delegates to the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator returned by `ArrayList` will fail with a `ConcurrentModificationException` if the list is modified after the iterator is created. For that reason, the code is preventing modifications to the list while iterating. Per the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) docs:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Not all `List` implementations have this particular behavior. For instance, with [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) iteration does not fail when there are concurrent modifications.